# super class field is not assigned to any value when spy() the real object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Following are my classes

```
class Parent{
    private AddressService addressService = ServiceLocator.getService(AddressService.class);

    protected void doSomeJob(){
        addressService.doThat();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{

    protected void doSomeJob(){
        super.doSomeJob();
    }

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceLocator.class})
class ChildTest{

    @Test
    public void doSomeJob(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
        AddressService addressService = Mockito.mock(AddressService.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceLocator.getService(AddressService.class)).thenReturn(addressService);

        Child original = new Child();
        Child spiedObj = PowerMockito.spy(original);
        spiedObj.doSomeJob();
    }

}
```

Here `ServiceLocator.getService()` is a static method which look-up and returns the bean from application context. So, I mocked that static class and ask to return `AddressService.class` instance when it ask for `ServiceLocator.getService(AddressService.class)`.

For my unit test when I `spy()/mock()` Child class that addressSerive instance have not assigned any value. But when I create a instance using `new` operator, I can see mock `AddressService` is assigned to the field. What am I missing here and how can I assigne value to that parent field when I do spy() on it's child instance?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a spy? just call `original.doSomeJob();` and verify on  `addressService`, no?

Comment: doSomeJob() will call few more methods internally and for which I want to use doNothing()/doReturn() as per my requirement. So, I want to spy() that original object.

Comment: Could you provide the problematic code ?

Comment: @gontard I cannot put actual code... So, i resemble the same here with different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't see any answers I tried following and it worked fine(which I tried to avoid doing)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceLocator.class})
class ChildTest{

    @Test
    public void doSomeJob(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
        AddressService addressService = Mockito.mock(AddressService.class);
        // commented as no more required
        // PowerMockito.when(ServiceLocator.getService(AddressService.class)).thenReturn(addressService);

        Child original = new Child();
        Child spiedObj = PowerMockito.spy(original);
        // using Whitebox API
        Whitebox.setInternalState(spiedObj, AddressService.class, addressService);
        spiedObj.doSomeJob();
    }

}
```

Here I have used `Whitebox` API to set member variable.